# How to write tests for emails using ActionMailer and resque_mailer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, rspec, actionmailer, resque

I am sending mail as part of a Rails controller action and am using ActionMailer as well as Resque::Mailer.

It doesn't really matter what background job library I use (Already using Resque for other things), but how can I write integration request specs for making a request that is supposed to trigger these emails?

Or is there some other kind of test I could write?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question correctly but I believe you can use should_receive and [email-spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) to test both if email was delivered in specific controller, and the content of those emails.

Example:

```
describe "POST /signup (#signup)" do
  it "should deliver the signup email" do
    # expect
    UserMailer.should_receive(:deliver_signup).with("email@example.com", "Jimmy Bean")
    # when
    post :signup, "Email" => "email@example.com", "Name" => "Jimmy Bean"
  end
end
```

Example 2:

```
describe "Signup Email" do
  include EmailSpec::Helpers
  include EmailSpec::Matchers
  # include ActionController::UrlWriter - old rails
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  before(:all) do
    @email = UserMailer.create_signup("jojo@yahoo.com", "Jojo Binks")
  end

  it "should be set to be delivered to the email passed in" do
    @email.should deliver_to("jojo@yahoo.com")
  end

  it "should contain the user's message in the mail body" do
    @email.should have_body_text(/Jojo Binks/)
  end

  it "should contain a link to the confirmation link" do
    @email.should have_body_text(/#{confirm_account_url}/)
  end

  it "should have the correct subject" do
    @email.should have_subject(/Account confirmation/)
  end

end
```